# How to configure gradle dependency for tomcat lib folder?

Tags: java, gradle, tomcat, gradle-dependencies

Hi have a multiproject where I want one of the libs to be in the tomcat lib folder (usually would be log4j or some other common lib). Code is available at [github](https://github.com/i23098/gradle8experiment) and dependencies are:

- regularLibA depends on commons-text
- regularLibB depends on commons-text and commons-lang3
- tomcatLib depends on regularLibA
- webApp depends on regularLibA, regularLibB and tomcatLib

With the simple build files/dependencies, the generated war file is:

```
webApp
├── index.jsp
└── WEB-INF
    ├── classes
    │   └── com
    │       └── github
    │           └── i23098
    │               └── web
    │                   └── W.class
    └── lib
        ├── commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar
        ├── commons-text-1.10.0.jar
        ├── regularLibA.jar
        ├── regularLibB.jar
        └── tomcatLib.jar
```

How to configure gradle so that tomcatLib project is to be in the tomcat lib folder, so, the jar and it's dependencies should not be added to the war file? i.e. the generated war file should be:

```
webApp
├── index.jsp
└── WEB-INF
    ├── classes
    │   └── com
    │       └── github
    │           └── i23098
    │               └── web
    │                   └── W.class
    └── lib
        ├── commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar
        └── regularLibB.jar
```

Also, how to create copy task of those files (tomcatLib.jar, regularLibA.jar and commons-text-1.10.0.jar) to the tomcat lib folder (i.e. how to get the list of excluded files from the war)?

Comment: Just to clarify, you wrote you want tomcatLib in the tomcat lib folder, but in the tree listing (second one), it is contained in webapp/lib. I suppose that tree listing is not correct?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to remove that one as well, will adjust it

Answer (score 0):

Use the Gradle War Plugin.

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
}
```

It adds two dependency configurations, `providedCompile` and `providedRuntime`, which cause the dependency not to be included in the war file. Configure your dependencies as necessary, for example:

```
dependencies {
    providedRuntime 'tomcatLib'
    providedCompile 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.10.0'
    ...
}
```

As far as copying jars to the Tomcat lib directory is concerned, you can use the Copy task. See [Working With Files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html) in the Gradle docs for a good introduction how to do that.

Comment: Is it not possible to have gradle calculate it? In this simple case it already means I have to check all dependencies of tomcatLib, for it's dependencies (regularLibA) check the dependencies of the dependency (commons-text) to know what should go into the lib folder. If it was a more complex project, with more project dependencies, it could be a bit complex and error prone. I was thinking in marking somehow the tomcatLib and then have gradle do all the work...

Comment: Also, if regularLibA later gets removed, would have to again edit the build file so that commons-text no longer would go to the tomcat lib folder.

It would be much better if there was a way to do all this dependency evaluation dynamically/programatically in gradle instead of manually specifying the providedCompile...

Comment: In terms of steps, what I was thinking was something like:

After gradle calculates dependencies, loop through all the java projects and if it's a tomcat lib (marked with a plugin? some ext.prop?), mark recursevly all dependencies as tomcat libs as well (so that the dependency tree also become tomcat libs) and store it in a list somehow.

When building the war file, exclude from the lib folder all those files in the previous list.

Have another task that copies all those files in the previous list to some dist directory (to be copied to tomcat/lib)